# On-topic help page edit preview is inaccurate on our serif-font site

Tags: bug, design, help-center

Moderators can edit [the on-topic help page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (It's the only help page we can edit.)

As you can see, that page shows up as sans-serif:

> [image: a screenshot of the page in sans-serif font]

However when editing the post preview uses our standard serif formatting we see on posts:

> [image: a screenshot of the post preview using serif font]

My expectation is the font would be sans-serif in the preview if it's sans-serif on the page.

This in particular gives some misleading impressions about what the heading formatting's going to look like. Left: nice and bold. Right: not.

> [image: serif heading, as compared to...] [image: sans-serif heading]

Comment: It looks like it's pulling in the exact same styling for the preview window as for the post editing pages. It's not just the serifs but also the link underlines, size... etc.